# Memory management in php for objects allocation

Tags: php, memory-management

```
for($count = 1;$count < =5; $count++){

    $obj = new Object();
    .
    .
    .

}
```

my question here is, if i do this, which segment of the memory will be occupied and also, will i have memory allocated for 5 objects, or just for one and it will be overwritten at every iteration

Comment: I think you are overriding `$obj`. So only single memory segment will be used

Comment: stored in the heap, get to know more about `debug_zval_dump` to see if it's overwritten

Comment: You are overriding $obj, but this does not mean, the memory is freed. This will be decided by the PHP internal garbage collector. The memory will be forced to get freed when you `$obj = null;`.

Comment: @lessan Kindly accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario only single memory segment will be allocated. If you want multiple memory segments to be allocated then you should change your code like below

```
for($count = 1;$count < =5; $count++){

${"obj" . $count} = new Object();

}
```

Comment: That assignment looks fatal.  Try: `${'obj'.$count}`.

Comment: @Progrock Oh no, I thought it worked same as javascript. Now I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

All your objects are named `$obj`, in fact you only have one object,so only take up single  memory.
If you want to have memory allocated for 5 objects，you need to name them different names.